# sort numbers numerically and strings alphabetically in an array perl

Tags: perl, sorting, numeric, alphabetical-sort

It's a very easy problem but can't get my way around it. I have an array

```
@arr = qw(txt text anothertext 38.09 100.87 0.876)
```

How can I sort the numbers in the array numerically and the strings alphabetically. So the output would look like, either:

```
@sorted_as = (anothertext text txt 100.87 38.09 0.876)
```

or,

```
@sorted_des = (txt text anothertext 100.87 38.09 0.876)
```

Sorry if I duplicate any question but could not find a suitable answer.

Comment: Shouldn't `@sorted_as = (anothertext text txt 0.876 38.09 100.87)` ? I assume `_as` means as ascending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide into 2 lists, sort each individually, then combine back into 1 list.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr = qw(txt text anothertext 38.09 100.87 0.876);

my @word =         sort {$a cmp $b} grep {  /^[a-z]/i } @arr;
my @num  = reverse sort {$a <=> $b} grep { !/^[a-z]/i } @arr;
my @sorted_as = (@word, @num);
print "@sorted_as\n";
```

Outputs:

```
anothertext text txt 100.87 38.09 0.876
```

To get des also, add these lines:

```
@word = reverse @word;
my @sorted_des = (@word, @num);
print "@sorted_des\n";
```

Comment: how do I tweak it, if my array is actually an array of hashes? currently I have `sort { $b->{$key} cmp $a->{$key} } @array_of_hashes`

Comment: @tt_pre Then just replace `$a` with `$a->{$key}` and $b the same way in both sort-blocks in the answer from @toolic. You also need `grep {$$_{$key}=~/^[a-z]/i}` and the other one where `=` becomes `!` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Sort::Key::Multi](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural):

```
# urns = (u)nsigned int, (r)everse (n)umber, (s)tring
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( urnskeysort );

my @sorted =
   urnskeysort {
      /^[0-9]/
         ? ( 1, $_, "" )
         : ( 0, 0, $_ )
   }
      @unsorted;
```

Similarly, you can use `urnrskeysort` for the second order.

Comment: sorry can't use packages. any solution with native perl 5.18?

Comment: This should be easy to adapt to `sort`, especially if you use it as part of a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)